# How to create signed url to fetch private content from cloud front in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, openssl

I am developing iOS app in swift. We need to fetch images from amazon cloud front . I am able to fetch private content from cloud front in Objective C using openssl library in Xcode 6.4 [using this reference link.](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=336955)

But I am using same library in swift , so getting importing error.
Please suggest it , How to create signed url for amazon cloud front to access private content in iOS.

If any other library to create signed url for amazon cloud front, please suggest it.

Answer (score 4):

There is a great [lib](https://github.com/TakeScoop/SwiftyRSA) for that :) And this is a full code in Swift 2:

```
lazy var signedURL: String = {
    let epochTime = NSDate().dateByAddingTimeInterval(60*5).timeIntervalSince1970
    let resourceURL = "resource url"
    let keyPairId = "your pair id"

    let keyPairPrivateKeyName = "name of pem file"


    let myurl = String(format: "%@?Expires=%.0f&Signature=%@&Key-Pair-Id=%@",
                       resourceURL,
                       epochTime,self.getSignature(resourceURL, expiresOn: epochTime, privateKey: keyPairPrivateKeyName), keyPairId)

    return myurl        
}()

func encodeStringForCloudFront(signature aSignature: String) -> String {
    var signature = aSignature

    signature = signature.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("+", withString: "-")
    signature = signature.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("=", withString: "_")
    signature = signature.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("/", withString: "~")

    return signature;
}

func getSignature(resourceURL: String, expiresOn: NSTimeInterval, privateKey keyPairPrivateKeyName: String) -> String {

    let signString = String(format: "{\"Statement\":[{\"Resource\":\"%@\",\"Condition\":{\"DateLessThan\":{\"AWS:EpochTime\":%.0f}}}]}", resourceURL, expiresOn)

    guard let filePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(keyPairPrivateKeyName, ofType: "pem"),
        let privateKeyData = NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: filePath)) else {
            return "Error loading pem file."
    }

    guard let str = String(data: privateKeyData, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) else {

        return "Private Key Data is not valid"
    }

    do {
        let signatureString = try SwiftyRSA.signString(signString, privateKeyPEM: str)

        return self.encodeStringForCloudFront(signature: signatureString)
    } catch {
        return "Something goes wrong URL NotValid"
    }
}
```

Comment: Bro, This line showing error. try SwiftyRSA.signString(signString, privateKeyPEM: str).

Answer (score 0):

As the linked thread states, it is extremely insecure to embed the Amazon CloudFront certificates on mobile devices.

Instead of generating the pre-signed URL on iOS, you should have a server and generate the pre-signed URL on your server. See [Serving Private Content through CloudFront](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/PrivateContent.html) for more details on how to do this.

Comment: I need to generate signed url from swift in Demo app. Please suggest it , How to use create signed url using openssl in swift app.

Answer (score -1):

> How to create signed url for amazon cloud front to access private content in iOS.

Its not clear to me what this has to do with OpenSSL. I also don't know what a signed URL is. Perhaps its a Amazon or Cloud Front marketing term.

With that said, I believe Python uses self authenticating URLs. A user agent can check authenticity of a package by visiting a URL based on a digest of the package. If the server responds with a 200, then its valid; otherwise its invalid. There's no page backing the URL.

Its not clear to me what you are trying to do, so I should probably stop there. For more reading, see:

- Peter Gutmann's [Engineering Security](http://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/%7Epgut001/pubs/book.pdf), around page 384
- [Python self authenticating URLs](https://www.google.com/search?q=python+self+authenticating+URLs)

You can use OpenSSL to create a self authenticating URL. You will have to modify the Base64 encoder, however. The default Base64 encoder uses the the standard [Base64 alphabet from the old days](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4648#page-5) (dating back to the 1980s and email). For web gear, you usually need to use the [Base64 with the web safe alphabet](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4648#page-6).